# How can I export a Trac 0.12.3 database of tickets, including all comments?

Tags: export, jira, export-to-csv, trac

I don't see a way in Trac to export entire tickets. You can save as tab- or comma-separated from a query, but that just exports the column values shown in the query. It definitely does not export the comments.
I want to then import those Trac tickets into Jira Software.

Answer (score 0):

Some versions of Jira have a Trac importer at Admin, System, External Import. Test in a non-production Jira of course. Support for this appears to stop after Jira 8.4 even if the feature is still present.

Otherwise you have to get a CSV file of the Trac data and use the Jira CSV Importer. Sounds like you may end up writing a script to extract and format the data from the Trac DB

Comment: https://help.cloudforge.com/hc/en-us/articles/215243223-How-to-export-from-Trac-tickets-into-TeamForge has some info about exporting from Trac into CSV